# Name element in *.csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So, being completely obsessive compulsive, I was digging around in the `.csproj` file for one of my assemblies and was looking at the schema for the XML. I noticed in the `<ItemGroup>`, the various `.dll` files are referenced using an element called `<Reference Include="..." />`.

Out of curiosity, I did some digging and found that I can change things up a bit by modifying it with an included `<Name>` element. Like so ...

```
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp">
      <Name>System.Dynamics</Name>
  </Reference>
```

I of course expected this to crash everything, but behold, when I reloaded the project and compiled, everything ran just fine.

Is this just there for aesthetics? Or am I doing damage by changing names around? Are there any long term effects of this? I did not experience any build, runtime, or editor issues from doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's just the display name of the reference.

Edit: The MSBuild schema defines the Reference\Name element as "Friendly display name (optional)."

The schema for MSBuild is located here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.xsd

Also, check out the [MSBuild Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

Comment: This is really groovy. You know what would be awesome? If we could separate the referenced assemblies up simply with faux folders. Like put all of `NHibernate` and its related .dlls under one 'folder', all of the native `.NET` dlls into one folder, all of the project .dlls in another... It's just the clean freak in me talking, I'm sure. It would not really serve any real purpose.

Comment: Older, but still relevant can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983950(v=VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Check out the schema: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.xsd